# neo4J query for property with special character or url

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to query the following in neo4j

match (n) where n.@audit="true" return n

It is complaining for "@". Same is the case when property is a url as per image attached[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a property key contains special characters, you'll need to surround the key name with backtick characters. So use:

n.`@audit`